# I made a selection from a csv file and need to sum up one of the columns in python

Tags: python, csv

I asked this question previously and received my answer. Now I need to sum up the column  to print one line with the total number.

*I am new to python and I have a csv file that i need to select certain rows based on characters after the third "_".

this is the sample from the csv file:

```
header row
date,ttp_ws_sm_001_01, , , , , , , , , , , ,117
date,ttp_ws_sm_001_blank, , , , , , , , , , , ,31
date,ttp_ws_sm_045_01, , , , , , , , , , , ,145
date,ttp_ws_sm_057_blank, , , , , , , , , , , ,98
date,ttpv1_001_, , , , , , , , , , , ,67
date,ttpv1_001_01, , , , , , , , , , , ,67*
```

This is the code that solved the first item that I am building on:

```
with open(...) as f:
    rows = csv.reader(f)
    for row in rows:
        t = row[1].split('_')
        if len(t) >= 4 and t[3] == '001':
            print (row[1], row[13])
```

Results:

```
('ttp_ws_sm_001_01', '117')
('ttp_ws_sm_001_blank', '31')
```

What I need to do is add the 117 & 31 so that I can print one line with just the total number. This is what I have tried so far and get a giant list.

```
import csv
import sys

total = 0
source = '\\\\file path' 
with open(source + '\filename') as f:
    rows = csv.reader(f)

    for row in rows:
        t = row[1].split('_')
        if len(t) >= 4 and t[3] == '001': 
            for number in range(13):    
                total += int(row[13])
                 print ('Club 001' + '\t' + str(total))
```

Comment: un-indent your last line, it's getting called for every iteration of your loop of loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the inner for loop you're summing up all the values 13 times. I'm not sure if it was intentional.

If I were to just sum up the values I'd do something like:

```
import csv
import sys
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    total = 0
    source = '.'
    with open(os.path.join(source, 'data.csv'), 'r') as f:
        rows = csv.reader(f)
        for row in rows:
            try:
                t = row[1].split('_')
            except IndexError:
                continue
            if len(t) >= 4 and t[3] == '001': 
                total += int(row[13])
    print ('Club 001' + '\t' + str(total))
```